# Datatables (jQuery) - sum ALL rows

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have the following, which successfully counts up the total of row on a SINGLE page of a datatable. How do I get the sum off ALL rows in the group, rather than just the ones on any single page?

```
rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: 0,

        startRender: function (rows, group) {
            var sum = rows
                .data()
                .pluck(3)
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return a + b * 1;
                }, 0);

            return $('<tr/>')
                .append('<td colspan="3">' + group + ' - Total Coverages: ' + sum + '</td>')
        }

  .append('<td colspan="3">' + group + ' - Coverages: ' + totCov + '</td>')
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is the `rows` parameter in `startRender` and `endRender` cover only those rows displayed on the current page.  If you want to calculate all rows then you will need to use [filter()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) to filter the table based on the `group` and calculate the sum.  Here is an example:

```
    rowGroup: {
      endRender: function ( rows, group ) {
        var filteredData = $('#example').DataTable()
          .rows()
          .data()
          .filter( function ( data, index ) {
            return data[2] == group ? true : false;
          } )
          .pluck(5)
          .sum();
        return group +' ('+rows.count()+' rows on page, $' + filteredData + ' salary total all pages)';
    },
        dataSrc: 2
    }
```

Basically it filters column 2 and then sums column 5 from the filtered rows. It displays the number of rows in the current page and the total salary, for the group, over all the pages.

The `sum()` method comes from the [sum() plug-in](//https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()).  You can see the example here:
http://live.datatables.net/fazigehi/1/edit

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.